# Opentext RightFax C# files

Tags: rightfax

I'm tasked to reconfigure RightFax to login with a smartcard aka client certificate. After extensive research and trial and error I can't figure out how to do this.

I tried going through active directory and that didn't work.

I tried IIS client certificate mapping and that didn't work.

When I try to edit default.aspx.cs using vbscript it doesn't work.

I've tried located the C# classes and I can't find them.

Can anyone help with me?

I know I can call the web service located in the openserver.aspx file but I can't get the application to retrieve the client cert first. I've edited the service once before to automatically log me into an account but now I need it to log me in using a client certificate.

Note: I pull the login information from the card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the application is in ASP classic.

C# is not allowed.

I'm kicking myself for finding this out.